# Where is `mail.from` in application.conf defined?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I noticed the following configuration in an `application.conf`:

```
mail.from ="dwplaydemo <mailrobot@dwplaydemo.net>
```

I suppose it has to do with `Play`'s support for sending emails. However I couldn't find where `mail` object is defined. Where could I find all the properties I could configure in `mail`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you are following [IBM's tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-playful-web-dev-1-trs-bluemix/index.html) on web development with the Play Framework and Scala.

If you look up the class `Mailer` in `app/utils/Mailer.scala` from the source code that has been provided with the tutorial, you will see that `mail.from` simply has been defined to externalize the sender property.

```
class Mailer @Inject() (configuration: Configuration, mailer: MailerClient) {
  val from = configuration.getString("mail.from").get
  val replyTo = configuration.getString("mail.reply")
  ...
```

This class depends on [`play-mailer`](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer). For a full list of configuration properties of this mailer, see the [Getting Started section](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer#getting-started) of the project's GitHub page.